# Why Riemann integral is not direction invariant

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, riemann-integration, riemann-sum

Denote for $f(x)$ - some Riemann integrable function.
Given a partition $\{x_0 = a, x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n = b\}$ of $[a, b]$ we define a lower Darboux Sum
$\underline{S} = \sum\limits_{i}\min\limits_{x \in [x_{i-1}, x_i]}f(x)(x_i - x_{i-1})$ and respectively an upper Darboux Sum $\bar{S}$.

I see this as a sum of rectangle areas, where sign is only inherited from the value of $f(x)$, while $(x_i-x_{i-1})$ is just the length of the rectangle basis.

[image: nice visualization of some random function with few Darboux rectangles]

What bothers me, is that

> the length of the rectangle basis is independent of the direction I'm
>   looking on it (from right or from left), then why does the sign of the
>   integral is **not** independent of the direction?

i.e., why
$$\int\limits_a^b f(x) \mathrm{d}x = -\int\limits_b^a f(x) \mathrm{d}x$$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For $a<b$, we *define* $\int_a^b f(x)\textrm{d}x$ as the supremum of the lower Darboux sums. On the other hand, we *define* $\int_b^a f(x)\textrm{d}x=-\int_a^b f(x)\textrm{d}x$ in order to make the identity

$$
\int_a^b f(x)\textrm{d}x+\int_b^c f(x)\textrm{d}x=\int_a^c f(x)\textrm{d}x
$$
hold no matter the relation of $a,b$ and $c$.

Alternatively, when integrating from $a$ to $b,$ you observe a partition $a=x_0<x_1<...x_n<b$ and observe the Riemann sums $\sum_{j=1}^n f(\xi) (x_j-x_{j-1})$. The analogous construction when integrating from $b$ to $a$ would be to observe a partion $b=x_0>x_1>...>x_n=a$ and the corresponding Riemann sums $\sum_{j=1}^n f(\xi) (x_j-x_{j-1})$, and here, the $x_j-x_{j-1}$ is a *negative* increment. This is another way to intuit that this convention might be useful.